# Why NPM is not available in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker

I am very new to docker and playing with it. I am trying to run nodejs app in docker container. I took ubuntu:14.04 as base image and build my own nodeJS baked image. My `Dockerfile` content looks like below

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER nmrony

#install packages, nodejs and npm
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install build-essential && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

#Copy the sources to Container
COPY ./src /src
CMD ["cd /src"]
CMD ["npm install"]

CMD ["nodejs", "/src/server.js"]
```

I run container using following command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d --name nodejs_expreriments nmrony/exp-nodejs
```

It runs fine. But when I try browse `http:localhost:8080` it does not run.
When I run `docker logs nodejs_expreriments`, I got the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/src/server.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I run another container with interactive shell and found that npm is not installed. Can someone help me why NPM is not installed on container? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that you can only have exactly *one* `CMD` in a Docker file.  Each `RUN`/`COPY` command builds up a layer during `docker build`, so you can have as many of those as you want.  However, exactly *one* `CMD` gets executed during a `docker run`.  Since you have three `CMD` statements, only one of them actually gets executed (presumably, the last one).

(IMO, if the Dockerfile team would have chosen the word `BUILD` instead of `RUN` and `RUN` instead of `CMD`, so that `docker build` does BUILD statements and `docker run` does RUN statements, this might have been less confusing to new users.  Oh, well.)

You either want to convert your first two `CMD`s to `RUN`s (if you expect them to happen during the `docker build` and be baked into the image) or perhaps put all three `CMD`s in a script that you run.  Here's a few solutions:

(1) The simplest change is probably to use `WORKDIR` instead of `cd` and make your `npm install` a `RUN` command.  If you want to be able to `npm install` during building so that your server starts up quickly when you run, you'll want to do:

```
#Copy the sources to Container
COPY ./src /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
CMD nodejs server.js
```

(2) If you're doing active development, you may want to consider something like:

```
#Copy the sources to Container
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./src/package.json /src/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY /src /src
CMD nodejs server.js
```

So that you only have to do the npm install if your package.json changes.  Otherwise, every time *anything* in your image changes, you rebuild *everything*.

(3) Another option that's useful if you're changing your package file often and don't want to be bothered with both building and running all the time is to keep your source *outside* of the image on a volume, so that you can run without rebuilding:

```
...
WORKDIR /src
VOLUME /src
CMD build_and_serve.sh
```

Where the contents of `build_and_serve.sh` are:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install && nodejs server.js
```

And you run it like:

```
docker run -v /path/to/your/src:/src -p 8080:8080 -d --name nodejs_expreriments nmrony/exp-nodejs
```

Of course, that last option doesn't give you a portable docker image that you can give someone with your server, since your code is *outside* the image, on a volume.

Lots of options!

Answer (score 7):

For me this worked:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g react-tools
```

My debian image apt-get was getting a broken/old version of npm, so passing a download path fixed it.

Comment: Tacking on npm commands to the same RUN that installed nvm was the only solution that made 'npm' usable in a Dockerfile. Thanks!

Comment: I had to remove '&& npm install -g react-tools' and add few more libs for ruby and it worked thank you